# Why background image doesn't show up?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have this code in html and css. the problem is that the background image doesn't show up. first I thought the problem is with the size of the image and I made it smaller. but it made no change. can anyone help spotting the problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
        <style>
            {background-image:url('background.png');}
        </style>
    </head>
    <title>
        Melika Barzegaran Hosseini - Home Page
    </title>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe change your CSS to:

`body{background-image:url('background.png');}`

At present you have no [CSS selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) in place to identify exactly 'what' to apply the background image to.

Failing that, ensure that the image is actually found at the location specified.

Comment: @Melika Barzegaran Hosseini no problem, we've all been there :)

Comment: it helped. I can accpet it 4 mins later. :)